# In R, are vectors and data frames considered ordered or unordered sets?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector

When teaching people R, I basically teach them to assume that data frames do not have an inherent order. In other words, each row is an independent observation, and, to use more mathematical terms, that data frames are unordered sets. I view data frames this way because long before learning R, I learned SQL, and the SQL standard makes it clear that there are no guarantees about the order of the records in tables or the order that queries will return results (it's basically implementation dependent). For me, this is the safest assumption for R, because it means I will always manually order things when needed, which should never lead to unexpected behavior (assuming I don't make my own mistakes in the ordering).

The problem is, that a lot of people coming to R, including the people I teach, don't have anywhere near the same type of programming or database background that I do. So it's really common to see people make the opposite assumption because it's less work and it never gives them trouble. And to be fair, it's probably a safe assumption, at least in the case of base R. But then you get into user contributed packages that may or may not be making the same consideration. Given that the assumption never causes them issues, it's sometimes hard to convince people to be careful in thinking about these things (and I'm currently exploring an issue, albeit somewhat corner case, where it could be relevant from a practical perspective for a lot of people).

So as I wrangle with this, one thing that would be a great help is official documentation on the matter. The problem is that I have yet to find an explicit confirmation about data frame row order in the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html). One thing that is a little helpful is the part on [data frames](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Data-frame-objects) that explicitly states that the numbers many people think of as row numbers are actually row names (R just uses numbers as a reasonable default), and I can illustrate these aren't just row numbers easily with:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = 5:1, b = 3:7)
> df
  a b
1 5 3
2 4 4
3 3 5
4 2 6
5 1 7
> df2 <- df[-3, ]
> df2
  a b
1 5 3
2 4 4
4 2 6
5 1 7
>
```

But is there anything more formal available? Something along the lines of "users should not assume data frames have an implicit order"? Or, conversely, is there anything that explicitly states users can depend on the row order in data frames, at least for base R?

Comment: A data.frame is a list of vectors. A vector is stored in a certain order with pointers to the previous and next element. A data.frame is ordered. See here for the memory storage reference: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/memory.html

Answer (score 0):

I've read many R docs but haven't seen anything formal written down about data frames being unordered or non-ordered sets. That's not to say that it isn't written somewhere since the documentation is quite extensive.

I've taught database concepts to students for many years and I always tell them that tables have no particular ordering apart from the data entry order, which usually have no meaning to the end-user. Same for the results of queries. When I teach R, I tell them the same for data frames - the order of the rows has no particular meaning other than to say that this is how the records may have been entered originally. The row names, whether you like them or not, are an attribute of the data frame, and should not be confused with the row index number, although they may be the same.

Now then, some user-contributed package authors have muddied the waters somewhat with special types of data frames, the "tbl_df" from the package "tibble" being a prime example. Where the rownames attribute of a "data.frame" is preserved when a subset is taken, the rownames for a "tbl" are not. The following example demonstrates:

```
> df <- data.frame(a = 5:1, b = 3:7)
> df
  a b
1 5 3
2 4 4
3 3 5
4 2 6
5 1 7

> df[2,]
  a b
2 4 4

> rownames(df[2,])
[1] "2"

> library(tibble)
> dt <- as_tibble(df)
> dt
# A tibble: 5 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     5     3
2     4     4
3     3     5
4     2     6
5     1     7

> dt[2,]
# A tibble: 1 x 2
      a     b
  <int> <int>
1     4     4

> rownames(dt[2,])
[1] "1"
```

I like tibbles though. One of the nice features, and there are many, is that rownames have a lighter shade of grey (you can't see it here). So new R users can see that they are not variables in the data, but they are there, possible for some useful purpose which may not be immediately apparent. I tell my students that the rownames are not necessarily the index number and not to bother too much with rownames, or the ordering for that matter.